# Record Video for Windows 7 no Download

Tags: windows-7, video

Is there a way to record a video of your desktop for Windows 7 that doesn't involve downloading a program?

Answer (score 2):

Closest you can get is Problem Steps Recorder. It's not really a video, but you don't have to install anything. Type it in to your search bar. (I don't know any other way to find it, anybody know?)